# Algorithm to group tree nodes with single successors

Tags: algorithm, tree, grouping

I have a graph data structure like the one below.

[image: Original Tree]

What would be the algorithm to group the nodes that have only a single child into one node? For example, the above tree would be converted into the following:

[image: Modified Tree]

The graph can have chains of nodes of arbitrary length, and can also loop back on itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following recursive algorithm solves your problem. Note that your input graph is not really a tree, but a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (however, the algorithm works properly on DAGs too). I'm assuming that your DAG is [topologically sorted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) and that you feed the DAG's root to the `group` function. If your DAG is not topologically sorted, you should first perform a topological sort, which can be done in linear time using [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

```
group(dag_node):
   if dag_node.num_children == 0:
      new_node = new DagNode(dag_node.value)
   if dag_node.num_children > 1:
      new_node = new DagNode(dag_node.value)
      new_node.children = [group(child) for child in dag_node.children]
   if tree_node.num_children == 1:
      value_pair = (dag_node.value, dag_node.children[0].value)
      new_node = new DagNode(value_pair)
      new_node.children = dag_node.children[0].children
      new_node = group(new_node)
   return new_node
```

Comment: I forgot to clarify that the DAG (thanks for the correction) can have chains of nodes of arbitrary length, and can also loop back on itself. The question will be edited.

Comment: @konsolas: I've made a correction to the algorithm so now it works correctly even if the DAG contains chians of arbitrary lengths.